# ASP.NET IActionResult Detail(int id) id is 0 even though I try to access /Detail/1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to access the page localhost/Catalog/Detail/{id}, but the Visual Studio is telling me my id = 0 when I trying to access for example localhost/Catalog/Detail/1 
any reason why is this happening? Below are the Controller for the View.

```
public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        var asset = _assets.GetById(id);

        var model = new AssetDetailModel
        {
            AssetId = id,
            Title = asset.Title,
            Year = asset.Year,
            Cost = asset.Cost,
            Status = asset.Status.Name,
            ImageUrl = asset.ImageUrl,
            AuthorOrDirector = _assets.GetAuthorOrDirector(id),
            CurrentLocation = _assets.GetCurrentLocation(id).Name,
            DeweyCallNumber = _assets.GetDeweyIndex(id),
            ISBN = _assets.GetIsbn(id)
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

The error I am getting is as below (due to the fact I am using FirstOrDefault to retrieve it, but as shown by Visual Studio, the value its receiving for int id is id = 0, so it will get me the default value which is null)

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

asset was null.
```

Just in case anyone asking
my routing template is

```
"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Update 1:
I've check the code source
I found that my Views are retrieving the correct @Model.ImageUrl and will give me a correct value as below (it retrieve emma.png if id = 1) but the picture wont be loaded in /Catalog/Detail/1, but will load in /Catalog and VS is tripping the error i mentioned above

```
<div>
<img src="detailImage" alt="/images/emma.png" />
</div>
```

[Error from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bigEm.jpg)

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be something like `/Home/Detail/1`?

Comment: @PeterB the Detail is under a Controller call Catalog, so I'm accessing /Catalog/Detail/{id} , I can access /Catalog just fine

Comment: [Edit]  the correct details in the question. If controller is Catalog and request is  /Catalog/Detail/{id} then that should be in the question

Comment: @Nkosi edited, sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting a question too early.
Found the problem, the problem is within the html tag that I've written for the img tag

I wrote

```
<div>
<img src="detailImage" alt="@Model.ImageUrl" />
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div>
<img class="detailImage" src="@Model.ImageUrl" />
</div>
```

Thanks for everyone who tried to help, need to take care of my shorthand syntax...